# How to add custom type definitions when using Typescript references in a Yarn workspace?

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to create a sample yarn workspace repo with Typescript's new references feature:

https://github.com/tommedema/serverless-mono-example/tree/feature/external-types

When an external library does not have type definitions, it should be possible to manually add these. What I've [done so far](https://github.com/tommedema/serverless-mono-example/commit/905f355aeeb44a12ecfa60393346577777628300):

1. created a `packages/types` workspace
2. added a sample at `packages/types/camelcase` with an `index.d.ts` file:

   `declare module 'camelcase' {
     export default function camelCase(
       strs: string | string[],
       options: {
         pascalCase?: boolean
       }
     ): string
   }`
3. updated a dependent package `packages/random`'s `tsconfig.json` to have a new reference to the types package:

   `{
     "extends": "../../tsconfig.settings.json",
     "compilerOptions": {
       "outDir": "dist",
       "rootDir": "src"
     },
     "references": [
       { "path": "../types" }
     ]
   }`
4. updated the `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.settings.json`:

   `"typeRoots": [
     "./node_modules/@types",
     "./packages/types"
   ],`

Yet despite having set both the references as well as the `typeRoots`, typescript is unable to find the type definition:

```
[ts]
Could not find a declaration file for module 'camelcase'. '/Users/tommedema/projects/vg/demos/serverless-mono-example/node_modules/camelcase/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/camelcase` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'camelcase';`
```

Is my use of typeroots invalid? Does it make sense to use references to accomplish this? Why can typescript not find the type definition?

Comment: I notice your `typeRoots` is declared 2 levels up from where your `tsconfig.json` is, so I wonder to which folder the `.` in `"./packages/types"` is referring: where `tsconfig.json` is or where `tsconfig.settings.json` is. Also, you didn't specify `"types"` in the tsconfigs right?

Comment: @MondKin the tsconfigs extend `../../tsconfig.settings.json`, see https://github.com/tommedema/serverless-mono-example/blob/feature/external-types/packages/random/tsconfig.json --- the relative path works from the location of the json file, as is evident from another example repo at https://github.com/Quramy/lerna-yarn-workspaces-example/blob/master/tsconfig.json. How can I "show my tree root"?

Comment: I removed the `"show my tree root"` part of my comment as I saw the repo with the source code was linked in the question.

Comment: I ran `tsc -b .` in `packages/random` and got `error TS6053: File '../types' not found.`  Looks like you are missing `tsconfig.json` in that directory if you want to use a TypeScript project reference.

Comment: That resolved it Matt. I've integrated it at https://github.com/tommedema/serverless-mono-example -- if you post it as an answer I can accept it. Basically the types folder requires a one liner: https://github.com/tommedema/serverless-mono-example/blob/master/packages/types/tsconfig.json